# How to make a clear table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to make my table view clear. I have used

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

but it does nothing. I have found that this is the solution in many places but it does not work for me. How do i do this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear the tableview background color and cell background color

In ViewDidLoad Write :

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath

after creating cell write

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: in the willDisplayCell method or another method?

Comment: @aviators54 - in viewDidLoad()